# Error when trying to activate the Content Organizer feature on a site

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule

I'm trying to activate the content organizer feature so I can have uploaded files automatically routed to a different library or folder.  When I try to activate it, I get this error:

> The Site scoped feature being activated has a dependency on hidden
>   Site Collection scoped feature
>   'FeatureDefinition/15/0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e' (ID:
>   '0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e'). Hidden features cannot be
>   auto-activated across scopes. There may be one or more visible Site
>   Collection scoped features that auto-activate the dependent hidden
>   feature.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked enabling the site collection feature SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Answer (score -1):

From this article:

https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2012/06/sharepoint-2010-features-names-and-their-guid-for-powershell.html

This feature is:

> Name: DocumentRoutingResources
>
> Title: Document Routing Resources
>
> ID: 0c8a9a47-22a9-4798-82f1-00e62a96006e
>
> Scope: Site

Try to manually activate the hidden "Document Routing Resources" Feature via PowerShell:

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity "DocumentRoutingResources" -Url http://sitecollection
```

Answer (score -2):

I just bumped into this in Office 365.

There is no need to force activate any hidden features.

The Content Organizer feature fails to activate due to dependencies with other features.

Ensure these features are activated and then content organizer should activate without issues.

**SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features**

**SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features**

Comment: Enabling these two features doesn't work to resolve the issue. Just tried it.